# How to specify Old and Even Row color in MVC Grid

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In view referred mvc grid as

```
@using GridMvc.Html
```

and under `<head>` referred Gridmvc.css and Bootstrap.min.css

I am binding data from model as

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{ 
 columns.Add(c => Name.Titled("Name");
 columns.Add(c => Amount.Titled("Amount Paid");
}).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)
```

How to specify different color to Odd and Even Rows.

Comment: Assuming you're using the correct version of Bootstrap, it should already be applying the `table-striped` class - are you trying to specify something else?

Comment: My requirement requires me to provide, add/In-line edit/delete functionality to the grid. So decided to go with Jquery Datatable . I am able to achieve all the functionality there. Thank you